# post возвращает пустую переменную

Tags: php, javascript

почему `alert` выдает `0`, а `php` возвращает , что переменная не определена

```
<script>
    function action_but(code, ttl, pid){
        $("#new_window .head span").html(ttl);
        $("#new_window").removeClass('hidden');
        alert(pid);
        $.post("assets/get.php", { act: pid, id: code })
        .done(function(data) {
          alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    }

    $(".constructor .result_category .add").click(function(){
        var code = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var ttl = $(this).closest(".data_footer").find("h2").text();
        var pid = $(this).closest(".ln").find("input[type=hidden]").val();
        if (pid == '') pid = 0;
        action_but(code, ttl, pid);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

php файл

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['act'])) {exit();}
$action = $_POST['act'];

define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/index.php';

define("IN_PARSER_MODE", "true");

@include('config.core.php');
    if (!defined('MODX_CORE_PATH')) define('MODX_CORE_PATH', $_SEVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/');

if ($action == 0){
    echo $action;
}else{
    echo "poc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В описании [функции `epmty`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) есть следующее:

> Переменная считается пустой, если она не существует или её значение равно FALSE.
>
> Следующие значения воспринимаются как пустые:
>
> - "" (пустая строка)
> - 0 (целое число)
> - 0.0 (число с плавающей точкой)
> - "0" (строка)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (пустой массив)

Так как передается `0` - функция считает, что значение *`empty`*.

Возможно стоит заменить проверку на: `!isset($var)`